# Even Google knows SO is the one

Tags: support, search, specific-question, google

Doing a Google [Search](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=c%23+deserialize+json&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) this evening I noticed the following interesting first result.
[image]

It seems that even Google knows that SO always has the answer, except the link points to the question [C# Automatic Property DeSerialization of JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945585/c-automatic-property-deserialization-of-json).

I am not sure if this is a bug, or if SO can even control what the Google crawler sees, but thought I would post it for interest sake anyway.

Comment: Impressive. I tried some other keywords, but no. *Why* is it the one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect only Google can answer this, but probably a situation where the incoming high value link is in the form of

`<a http="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345">this one</a>`

Comment: Fair enough. I suspected it is an edge case. But well worth the posting value.

Comment: I also first thought of that, so I googled for such a link using `link:`, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: @BalusC: What site do we know of that has lots of high value links to SO?  [This one.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373492/can-i-deserialize-a-json-string-into-an-object-if-i-only-know-the-parameters-of-t)

Comment: @Bill: Haha :) But seriously, it gives [0 hits](http://www.google.com/search?q=link%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F1373492).